# error en java al guardar datos en base de datos mysql

Tags: java, mysql

La siguente pregunta ya esta respondida y dejo el codigo para otra persona pueda trabajar con ella. Este es un codigo para conectar un programa java a una base de datos MySQL para poder guardar, editar, eliminar y mas cosas a la tabla en la base de datos.

lo tengo en 4 archivos asi que los ire poniendo uno debajo del otro

Este archivo se llama proyecto Final 10

```
package proyectofinal1.pkg0;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
*
* @author BEEO
*/
 public class Proyectofinal10 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    formulario2 form= new formulario2();
    form.setVisible(true);


}

}
```

Este es el archivo de la conexion con la base de datos

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


 public class conexion{

private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String USER = "root";
private static final String PASS = "102030";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contactos?serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false";
private Connection CN;

public conexion(){
CN = null;
}

public Connection getConnection(){

    try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            CN = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error al conectar al servidor", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    return CN;
    }

public void close(){
try{
    CN.close();
}catch(SQLException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage(), "Error al cerrar la conexion con la base de datos", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

}



 }
```

Este otro archivo es el que contiene el gui de la aplicacion, es decir, donde estan los botones, text field, etc, lo que ve quien usa el programa

Tuve que borrar la mayor parte que me genera el netbeans ya que la web solo me deja introducir 30.000 de caracteres

```
  import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

 public class formulario2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private final formularioFuncion FF;

int num;
public formulario2() {
    initComponents();
    FF= new formularioFuncion();
    verContactos();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

private void verContactos(){
    jtb_bd.setModel(FF.extraerDatos());
}

private void limpiarTF(){
    jtf_id.setText("");
    jtf_nombre.setText("");
    jtf_apellido.setText("");
    jtf_compañia.setText("");
    jtf_posicion.setText("");
    jtf_email.setText("");
    jtf_telefono.setText("");
    jta_notas.setText("");
    jtf_nombre.requestFocus();

}

private void editar(){

    String id = jtf_id.getText();
    String nom = jtf_nombre.getText();
    String apell = jtf_apellido.getText();
    String com = jtf_compañia.getText();
    String pos = jtf_posicion.getText();
    String emai = jtf_email.getText();
    String tele = jtf_telefono.getText();
    String not = jta_notas.getText();
    //String fot = jtf_nombre.getText();
    if (num == 0){


    int resp = FF.insertDatos(nom, apell, com, pos, emai, tele, not);
    if (resp > 0){
        verContactos();
        limpiarTF();
    }

    }else{
        int resp = FF.editarDatos(id, nom, apell, com, pos, emai, tele, not);
    if (resp > 0){
        verContactos();
        limpiarTF();
        num=0;

    }
    }
}        


            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jbt_guardar)
                .addComponent(jbt_eliminar)
                .addComponent(jbt_cargar_contactos)
                .addComponent(jbt_seleccionar_csv))
            .addGap(19, 19, 19))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jtf_compañiaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                            

private void jtf_telefonoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                            

private void jtf_idActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

private void jbt_guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    editar();
    /* String nom = jtf_nombre.getText();
    String apell = jtf_apellido.getText();
    String com = jtf_compañia.getText();
    String pos = jtf_posicion.getText();
    String emai = jtf_email.getText();
    String tele = jtf_telefono.getText();
    String not = jta_notas.getText();
    //String fot = jtf_nombre.getText();

    int resp = FF.insertDatos(nom, apell, com, pos, emai, tele, not);
    if (resp > 0){
        verContactos();
        limpiarTF();
    }*/
}                                           

private void jtf_filtroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void jtf_filtroKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    char tecla = evt.getKeyChar();
    if(tecla == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ){
        jtb_bd.setModel(FF.filtro(jcb_filtro.getSelectedIndex(), jtf_filtro.getText()));
    }
}                                      

private void jtb_bdMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    int row = jtb_bd.getSelectedRow();
    jtf_id.setText(jtb_bd.getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
    jtf_nombre.setText(jtb_bd.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
    jtf_apellido.setText(jtb_bd.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
    jtf_compañia.setText(jtb_bd.getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
    jtf_posicion.setText(jtb_bd.getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
    jtf_email.setText(jtb_bd.getValueAt(row, 5).toString());
    jtf_telefono.setText(jtb_bd.getValueAt(row, 6).toString());
    jta_notas.setText(jtb_bd.getValueAt(row, 7).toString());
    //jtf_foto.setText(jtb_bd.getValueAt(row, 8).toString());
    String estado = jtb_bd.getValueAt(row, 6).toString();
    if (estado.equals("5")){

    }
    num = 1;
}                                   

private void jbt_eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    int fila = jtb_bd.getSelectedRowCount();
    if (fila < 1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleccione un registro de la tabla");
    }else{
        if (FF.eliminar(jtb_bd.getValueAt(jtb_bd.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString()) > 0);
        limpiarTF();
        verContactos();

    }
}                                            

private void jbt_abrir_imagenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    JFileChooser dato= new JFileChooser();
    int op = dato.showOpenDialog(this);

    if(op==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
   // jTextField1.setText(dato.getSelectedFile().getPath());
    }
}                                                

private void jbt_cargar_contactosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     

}                                                    

private void jbt_seleccionar_csvActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    JFileChooser seleccionar = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filtro = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.csv", "csv");
    seleccionar.setFileFilter(filtro);
    seleccionar.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = seleccionar.getSelectedFile();
    //fileName = f.getAbsolutePath();

    /*int seleccion = seleccionar.showOpenDialog(this);
    //Si el usuario, pincha en aceptar
    if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        //Seleccionamos el fichero
        fichero = file.getSelectedFile();

        final JFileChooser elegirImagen = new JFileChooser();
    elegirImagen.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    int o = elegirImagen.showOpenDialog(this);*/


}                                                   



 }
```

Este ultimo archivo tiene las contine las funciones de los botones

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
 import proyectofinal1.pkg0.conexion;

public class formularioFuncion {

private final String QUERY_INSERT = "insert into cliente(nombre, apellido, compañia, posicion, email, telefono, notas) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
private final String QUERY_SELECT = "select * from cliente";
private PreparedStatement PS;
private DefaultTableModel DT;
private ResultSet RS;
private conexion CN;

public formularioFuncion(){
    PS = null;
    CN = new conexion();

}

private DefaultTableModel columDB(){
    DT = new DefaultTableModel();
    DT.addColumn("id");
    DT.addColumn("nombre");
    DT.addColumn("apellido");
    DT.addColumn("compañia");
    DT.addColumn("posicion");
    DT.addColumn("email");
    DT.addColumn("telefono");
    DT.addColumn("notas");
    //DT.addColumn("foto");
    return DT;


}

public int insertDatos(String nom,String apell,String com,String pos,String emai,String tele,String not){
    int res = 0;
    try{
        PS = CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(QUERY_INSERT);
        PS.setString(1, nom);
        PS.setString(2, apell);
        PS.setString(3, com);
        PS.setString(4, pos);
        PS.setString(5, emai);
        PS.setString(6, tele);
        PS.setString(7, not);
        //PS.setString(8, fot);
        res =PS.executeUpdate();
        if(res > 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro guardado exitosamente");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error al guardar los datos en la BD" + e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        PS=null;
        CN.close();
    }
    return res;

}

public int editarDatos(String id,String nom,String apell,String com,String pos,String emai,String tele,String not){
    String SQL = "update cliente set nombre='"+nom+"', apellido='"+apell+"', compañia='"+com
            +"', posicion='"+pos+"', email='"+emai+"', telefono='"+tele+"', notas='"+not+"' where id="+id;
    int res = 0;
    try{
        PS = CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL);
        res =PS.executeUpdate();
        if(res > 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro editado exitosamente");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error al editar los datos en la BD" + e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        PS=null;
        CN.close();
    }
    return res;

}

public int eliminar(String id){
    String SQL = "delete from cliente where id = " + id;
    int res = 0;
    try{
        PS = CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL);
        res =PS.executeUpdate();
        if(res > 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro eliminado exitosamente");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error al eliminar los datos en la BD" + e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        PS=null;
        CN.close();
    }
    return res;
}

public DefaultTableModel extraerDatos(){
    try{
        columDB();
        PS = CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(QUERY_SELECT);
        RS = PS.executeQuery();
        Object[] fila=new Object[8];
        while(RS.next()){
            fila[0]=RS.getInt(1);
            fila[1]=RS.getString(2);
            fila[2]=RS.getString(3);
            fila[3]=RS.getString(4);
            fila[4]=RS.getString(5);
            fila[5]=RS.getString(6);
            fila[6]=RS.getString(7);
            fila[7]=RS.getString(8);
            DT.addRow(fila);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error al extraer los datos de la BD" + e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        PS = null;
        RS = null;
        CN.close();

    }

    return DT;
}

public DefaultTableModel filtro(int crt, String info){
    String SQL = null;
    if(crt == 0){
        SQL = "select * from cliente where nombre like '" + info + "%'";
    }else if(crt == 1){
        SQL = "select * from cliente where apellido like '" + info + "%'";
    }else if(crt == 2){
        SQL = "select * from cliente where compañia like '" + info + "%'";
    }else if(crt == 3){
        SQL = "select * from cliente where telefono like '" + info + "%'";
    }
    try{
        columDB();
        PS = CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL);
        RS = PS.executeQuery();
        Object[] fila=new Object[8];
        while(RS.next()){
            fila[0]=RS.getInt(1);
            fila[1]=RS.getString(2);
            fila[2]=RS.getString(3);
            fila[3]=RS.getString(4);
            fila[4]=RS.getString(5);
            fila[5]=RS.getString(6);
            fila[6]=RS.getString(7);
            fila[7]=RS.getString(8);
            DT.addRow(fila);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error al extraer los datos de la BD" + e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        PS = null;
        RS = null;
        CN.close();

    }

    return DT;
}

/*private void importar(File a){
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename1));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
            String[]value = line.split(",");
            String SQL = "insert into cliente(nombre, apellido, compañia, posicion, email, telefono, notas)" + 
                        "values('"+value[0]+"', '"+value[1]+"', '"+value[2]+"', '"+value[3]+"', '"+value[4]+"', '"+value[5]+"', '"+value[6]+"'";
            PS = CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL);
            RS = PS.executeQuery();
        }
        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        System.out.println("Error al importar los datos en la BD" + e.getMessage());

    }


}*/
```

}

Comment: ¿Dónde está num?
Tu método dice que si num==0 haga una inserción de nuevos datos, pero nunca declaras num

Comment: Convendría que muestres el código del método `insertDatos` para ver lo que allí ocurre. Otra cosa, aunque `not` no es una [palabra reservada de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), yo no la usaría nunca como nombre de variable. Conviene que apliques una convención de nombres adecuada en tu código, quien lo lee se preguntará ¿qué significa `FF`? ¿qué significa `com`?  ¿qué significa `limpiarTF`?  ... hay que programar para que otros lean el código y también entiendan.

Comment: muchas gracias por las sugerencias, me reuni con un compañero que esta mas avanzado que yo y me ayudo a buscar el problema y como dice compañero el problema estaba en insertDatos (cosa que aun no entiendo, pero, ahi trato de explicar):  en la base de datos tengo el id como entero auto increment, tons, pense k debia ponerle en editarDatos(String id,String nom,String apell,String com,String pos,String emai,String tele,String not) tenia el id asi Int id y debe ser String id, con eso ya resolvi todo T_T, esa simplicidad.